# Imported Java classes cannot run

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

[image]

[image]

[image]

I imported a project from someone but when i open it the java files cannot run usually they appear as java class (as shown in the last snip) but instead they have an orange j symbol  (as shown in the first snip)  and cannot run how to fix this

Comment: Your src folder doesn't seem to be configured as a source folder. You probably want to right-click on it, and select "Mark directory as - sources root". You should also never, ever put classes in the default package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click on the src directory and then mark the directory as Source Root

[image]